# Override UIViewController.view with specific type

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Let's consider an application with highly customized or complex views.

We'll have a specific kind of view-controller sending methods to a specific kind of UIView, where the UIView is itself composed of a number of other views.

The view should have a rich, domain-specific interface, allowing the controller to act is a thin "glue" layer between it and a similarly rich model.

**So we override our controller's view property as follows:**

```
@interface PlaybackViewController : UIViewController<StageLayoutDelegate, ControlPanelDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray* _sections;
    LightingMode _lightingMode;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) PlaybackView* view; // <------ Specific type of view

#pragma mark - injected
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<OscClient> oscClient;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AbstractStageLayoutView* stageLayoutView;

@end
```

Ovverriding makes sense over defining another accessor, and I can just send messages to the specific type of UIView without having to cast.

**Problem:** The only problem is that it results in a compiler warning:

*property type 'PlaybackView *' is incompatible with type 'UIView *' inherited from 'UIViewController'*

. . and I like to build code that doesn't have any warnings. This way a valid warning doesn't get missed by being buried amongst other warnings.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to suppress this *particular* warning?
- Why is this part of the default settings, when most modern OO languages will happily allow overriding a property or method in a sub-class so that it returns a more specific sub-class of the type declared in the super-class?

Comment: Why aren't you creating, a view subclass and use the main VC view as a container? Apple suggests always composition over of subclassing

Comment: UITableViewController manages to do what you are talking about and as a result is inflexible to the point of being almost useless. I'd think hard about this approach. It may come back to bite you later.

Comment: This is a quick and dirty just to suppress the warning, try to wrap your code between these lines `#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"
//YOUR CODE
#pragma clang diagnostic pop` or -Wall

Comment: @JasperBlues I've edit my answer but, of course, try it before.

Comment: @KirbyTodd I agree that UITableViewController is of limited use, however I don't think its because its tightly coupled to a UITableView. .  there are many cases where a view-controller interfaces with a specific kind of view. . Doing this helps a controller take on its intended role of being a thin glue layer between a rich view and model.

Comment: I can't even reproduce your warning. Do you have additional flags setup? Is PlaybackView a UIView subclass?.

Comment: Im guessing not as when i make PlaybackView a NSObject subclass (rather than UIView) is when I see the warning.

Comment: @WarrenBurton That would make sense. But I'm getting the warning when PlaybackView is a kind of UIVIew. This still satisfies the contract of the super-class. Did you not get the warning for this case?

Comment: no. as soon as PlaybackView is UIView subclass the warning vanishes. Are you using a fwd declaration ie. @class PlaybackView; or #import "PlaybackView.h" ? Im using #import

Comment: Yes, I'm (over-zealously) using forward declarations. Care to provide an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is not not the override of the property, its using a forward declaration of the class type.

So this...

```
@class PlaybackView;

@interface PlaybackViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) PlaybackView* view;

@end
```

will give you the mentioned warning because the compiler cannot know the inheritance hierarchy of `PlaybackView`. `UIViewController` has a contract to provide a `UIView` from its `view` property

Its telling you that it thinks `PlaybackView` is not a `UIView`

The simple solution here is to use a `#import` instead to give the compiler full knowledge of `PlaybackView`...

```
#import "PlaybackView.h"

@interface PlaybackViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) PlaybackView* view;

@end
```

alternatively (but really bad form as the PCH is an optimising feature and shouldn't manage dependancies ) is to add `#import "PlaybackView.h"` to your projects PCH

Comment: Of course! So obvious (in retrospect). . will award the +100 bounty too, once the time's up.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in another answer using `#import` instead of `@class` will clear the warning but it is advised to import as little as possible in the header, so I would recommend leaving the `view` unchanged and having an additional `PlaybackView * playbackView`:

- It is perfectly fine to have both `view` and `playbackView` pointing to the same view.
- Classes that need to have knowledge of your specialized `view` have to import your controllers header, so they could just use `playbackView` in the first place.
- More important, if you want to embed your specialized view as a subview in the future (which happens often like adding a `UIScrollView` superview), you won't have to refactor other code and classes!
- It's plain cleaner.

Comment: It's definitely not cleaner in my opinion. It's confusing to the reader of the code to have another link to a very familiar construct. If you would add another IBOutlet you would have to venture to IB to see that it's actually the same thing as view. If you override it clearly in the ViewController you can see that it's in fact the .view. That base .view is what it is, a PlaybackView. I use the technique Warren Burton described a lot because I want to use that base view for view housekeeping duties that do not belong to a specific item inside that view.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think override UIViewControllers view property is a good way .

I think it is better to do like this :

```
@interface PlaybackViewController : UIViewController<StageLayoutDelegate, ControlPanelDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray* _sections;
    LightingMode _lightingMode;
}

//@property (nonatomic, strong) PlaybackView* view; //you do not need this property

#pragma mark - injected
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<OscClient> oscClient;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AbstractStageLayoutView* stageLayoutView;

@end
```

and in the .m file .

```
- (void)loadView
{
    PlaybackView *mainView = [[PlaybackView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    // set the mainView
    self.view = mainView;
}
```

and you can use your PlaybackView like this .

```
((PlaybackView *)(self.view)).oscClient
```

or

```
((PlaybackView *)(xxxViewControler.view)).oscClient
```

Comment: @JasperBlues In my opinion , it is more flexible , such as navigationBar.leftItem , we do not override leftItem , we just give leftItem a buttonItem. And if your view need sometimes to be PlaybackView1 type and sometimes to be PlaybackView2 type , just add a bool in the loadView can deal with it. And if you override , I think it is not easy to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]
Finally I've probably found a solution that suit the problem:
This is a quick and dirty just to suppress the warning, try to wrap your code between these lines

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu" 
//YOUR CODE
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

or -Wall
To see more about compiler warning suppression [Clang Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas)

[OLD ANSWER]

<s>I'd like to give my 2 cents.
If I understood well you are trying to create a sort of Abstract factory, that gives you a specialized version of a view based on the view controller funcionality. In my opinion storyboards doesn't work well in that kind of design, but I'd like to give you my vision about it.</s>

First I will create an abstract class for your view controller where in the interface you declare all property you need in all your VC sublcasses, such as :

- OSClient
- AbstractStageLayoutView
- **PlaybackView** as weak
- **playbackProperty**

The PlaybackView class is a class cluster such as NSNumber, you call a factory method on it, that will return an object that could be different from case to case. If you inspect an NSnumber it returns a different object if you create a float or an integer, but they are all subclasses of NSNumber, and NSNumber declares all the property of its subclasses, but it doesn't implement them.

Now what you can do in the -viewDidLoad method of the abstract class is call a method like that

```
PlaybackView *plbackView = [PlaybackView playbackViewFroProperty:self.playbackProperty];
[self.view addSubview:playbackView];
self.playbackView = plbackView;
```

The playbackProperty can be valued inside the `User defined runtime attibute` in the viewcontroller storyboard editor.

Comment: No, I'm sorry I must've worded the question badly. All that I'm trying to do is specify the type of my UIView in my UIViewController sub-class to be eg PlaybackView* (the abstract part was a red-herring). . . If you do this, clang actually gives a warning, forcing you instead to cast everywhere. For succinct code, I want to avoid the casting.

Comment: Now I understood, but I don't' have the answer :-(

Comment: Yes, sorry my question wasn't clear. . . I've added some more clarifications in the question to help explain what I mean. . What do you think? It seems like there *must* be a way, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: You can suppress compiler warnings wrapping your methods around two preprocessor macro, but the warning has its own reason. I don't know if it acceptable for you, but why do not create a sort of myView method that simple call the view method casting it

Comment: I've got one last suggestion, the I give up :) What about method swizzling, at runtime you swap a method implantation with another. I've never used it but If are not aware you should take a look https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html

Comment: View substitution isn't the problem.  The issue is the compiler warning.  Unfortunately, swizzling doesn't help with that.

Comment: @Andrea - swizzling won't help here. We want a specific type of controller to be (justifiably) tightly coupled to a specific type of view. So that the controller can call this view's particular interface without casting. . . It *can* already do this, but to avoid warnings we need to cast. See? Its a compile-time problem.

Comment: @Andrea, having said that nothing makes me happy than getting a chance to raise the swizzle-cannon :) Check out www.typhoonframework.org - we do some funky stuff with the ObjC runtime there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could declare another method that provides the cast for you, in a sense.

```
@implementation PlaybackViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //  use view_ property instead of view
    self.view_.foo = 1;
}

- (void)loadView {
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    self.view = [[PlaybackView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (PlaybackView *)view_ {
    return (PlaybackView *)self.view;
}
```

Not exactly the cleanest approach, but it does avoid the cast on `self.view` (by not using `self.view`, though)

Comment: That's like providing a different property, which he says he is not interested in.

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, the OP said _"property"_ not _"method"_.  I'll grant that modern ObjC syntax blurs the distinction.

Comment: @NSBum I think I said 'accessor' which does imply a property (synthesized or custom-method), but it was meant to imply 'method' as well. . . in any case thanks for the suggestion Leo Natan.

Comment: Fair enough.  I can't think of any other way to do this; though it is a chronic irritation.